# Access another classes's SharedPreferences from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a savePreferences and loadPreferences method written as follows in MyClass (which is an Activity):

```
 private void savePreference(String key, boolean value) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);    
      boolean toggleValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ToggleValue", true);
      Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean(key, value);
      editor.commit();      
 }

 public void loadPreferences() {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      boolean toggleValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ToggleValue", true);
      if (toggleValue) {
           toggle.setChecked(true);
           alertStatus=true;
      } else {
           toggle.setChecked(false);
           alertStatus=false;
      }
      myHold.setStatus(alertStatus);
 }
```

I also have a BroadCastReceiver class named MyBroadCast

In the `onReceive()` method of the `BroadCastReceiver`, I want to call `loadPreferences()` to load the preferences. How can I do so? I tried making an object of `MyClass` and calling `.loadPreferences()` but it would give me a null pointer exception in this line of the `loadPreferences` class:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static method inside your Activity to encapsulate the read calls to SharedPreferences:

```
public static boolean loadTogglePreferences(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ToggleValue", true);
}
```

To reduce code redundancy you might want to use this methods in you existing code:

```
public void loadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean toggleValue = loadTogglePreferences(this);
    toggle.setChecked(toggleValue);
    alertStatus = toggleValue;
    myHold.setStatus(alertStatus);
}
```

If you are reading more than a few itms from `SharedPreferences`, you should definitely reuse the `SharedPreferences` object instead of creating a new one for every item.

Or, you could just reference `"ToggleValue"` as a public static final String and read the default `SharedPreferences` in the receiver yourself:

```
public static final String PREFS_TOGGLE = "ToggleValue";
```

Comment: Im a little confused on your code. In the Receiver do I call loadTogglePreferences()? How do I call that?

Comment: you need to call `YourActivityClass.loadTogglePreferences(context)`